# BigQuery: UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I got an error stating that 'UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row' in BigQuery for the following original query below.

I then wrote the second query, that checked for duplicate rows in the previous statement. This returned that there were 75000+ rows that were duplicates and all were from table_2.

However when I ran the third query, which took the part of the original first query that selected the distinct rows from table_2, and added a grouping and count to see if there were any duplicate rows and it returned that there were not any duplicate rows.

This doesn't make sense. How do I ensure that there aren't any duplicate source rows for the merge to match destination rows to?

Original Query:

```
MERGE INTO `PROJECT.DATASET.DESTINATION_TABLE` destination_table
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    pat.payments_accounting_transaction_id
    , pat.company_account
    , pat.merchant_account
    , pat.merchant_reference
    , pat.psp_reference
    , pat.booking_date
    , pat.main_currency
    , pat.main_amount
    , pat.record_type
    , ats.user_id
    , ats.value
    , ats.charge
    , ats.result_code
    , ats.event_code
    , ats.contract_type
    , ats.statement_message
    , ats.load_type
  FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.SOURCE_TABLE_1` pat
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      psp_reference
      , merchant_account_code
      , user_id
      , value
      , charge
      , result_code
      , event_code
      , contract_type
      , statement_message
      , load_type
    FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.SOURCE_TABLE_2`
    WHERE psp_reference IS NOT NULL
     -- providing window for settlement process
    AND created >= DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-07-13T00:00:00+00:00'))
    AND created < DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2023-01-10T00:00:00+00:00'))
  ) ats ON pat.psp_reference = ats.psp_reference
    AND pat.merchant_account = ats.merchant_account_code
) source_table ON destination_table.psp_reference = source_table.psp_reference
    AND destination_table.merchant_account = source_table.merchant_account
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    destination_table.payments_accounting_transaction_id = source_table.payments_accounting_transaction_id
    , destination_table.company_account = source_table.company_account
    , destination_table.merchant_reference = source_table.merchant_reference
    , destination_table.booking_date = source_table.booking_date
    , destination_table.main_currency = source_table.main_currency
    , destination_table.main_amount = source_table.main_amount
    , destination_table.record_type = source_table.record_type
    , destination_table.user_id = source_table.user_id
    , destination_table.value = source_table.value
    , destination_table.charge = source_table.charge
    , destination_table.result_code = source_table.result_code
    , destination_table.event_code = source_table.event_code
    , destination_table.contract_type = source_table.contract_type
    , destination_table.statement_message = source_table.statement_message
    , destination_table.load_type = source_table.load_type
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
(
    payments_accounting_transaction_id
    , company_account
    , merchant_account
    , psp_reference
    , merchant_reference
    , booking_date
    , main_currency
    , main_amount
    , record_type
    , user_id
    , value
    , charge
    , result_code
    , event_code
    , contract_type
    , statement_message
    , load_type
)
VALUES
(
    source_table.payments_accounting_transaction_id
    , source_table.company_account
    , source_table.merchant_account
    , source_table.psp_reference
    , source_table.merchant_reference
    , source_table.booking_date
    , source_table.main_currency
    , source_table.main_amount
    , source_table.record_type
    , source_table.user_id
    , source_table.value
    , source_table.charge
    , source_table.result_code
    , source_table.event_code
    , source_table.contract_type
    , source_table.statement_message
    , source_table.load_type
)
;
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT 
  payments_accounting_transaction_id
  , company_account
  , merchant_account
  , merchant_reference
  , psp_reference
  , booking_date
  , main_currency
  , main_amount
  , record_type
  , user_id
  , value
  , charge
  , result_code
  , event_code
  , contract_type
  , statement_message
  , load_type
  , COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT 
    pat.payments_accounting_transaction_id
    , pat.company_account
    , pat.merchant_account
    , pat.merchant_reference
    , pat.psp_reference
    , pat.booking_date
    , pat.main_currency
    , pat.main_amount
    , pat.record_type
    , ats.user_id
    , ats.value
    , ats.charge
    , ats.result_code
    , ats.event_code
    , ats.contract_type
    , ats.statement_message
    , ats.load_type
  FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE_1` pat
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      psp_reference
      , merchant_account_code
      , user_id
      , value
      , charge
      , result_code
      , event_code
      , contract_type
      , statement_message
      , load_type
    FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE_2`
    WHERE psp_reference IS NOT NULL
     -- providing window for settlement process
    AND created >= DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-07-13T00:00:00+00:00'))
    AND created < DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2023-01-10T00:00:00+00:00'))
  ) ats ON pat.psp_reference = ats.psp_reference
    AND pat.merchant_account = ats.merchant_account_code
) 
GROUP BY 
  payments_accounting_transaction_id
  , company_account
  , merchant_account
  , merchant_reference
  , psp_reference
  , booking_date
  , main_currency
  , main_amount
  , record_type
  , user_id
  , value
  , charge
  , result_code
  , event_code
  , contract_type
  , statement_message
  , load_type
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Third Query:

```
SELECT 
    psp_reference
    , merchant_account_code
    , user_id
    , value
    , charge
    , result_code
    , event_code
    , contract_type
    , statement_message
    , load_type
    , COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
      psp_reference
      , merchant_account_code
      , user_id
      , value
      , charge
      , result_code
      , event_code
      , contract_type
      , statement_message
      , load_type
    FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE_2`
    WHERE psp_reference IS NOT NULL
     -- providing window for settlement process
    AND created >= DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-07-13T00:00:00+00:00'))
    AND created < DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2023-01-10T00:00:00+00:00')))
GROUP BY
    psp_reference
      , merchant_account_code
      , user_id
      , value
      , charge
      , result_code
      , event_code
      , contract_type
      , statement_message
      , load_type

HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: `ON` clause is not the same as `GROUP BY` clause. [Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rjbb2xoO) (in Oracle, but behaviour is the same).

Comment: @ma8701 I proposed you an answer and a solution. Can you check it please ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun I will check it as soon as I can. I will message you when I have. Sorry for the delay, will try to do so asap.

Answer (score 1):

If you want using `merge` query and deal with duplicates, you can use the following query :

```sql
MERGE `{{project_id}}.{{dataset}}.{{team_stat_table}}` T
USING (
    SELECT
        * EXCEPT (rn)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY teamName ORDER BY ingestionDate DESC) AS rn
        FROM `{{project_id}}.{{dataset}}.{{team_stat_staging_table}}`
        WHERE date(ingestionDate) = CURRENT_DATE()
    )
    WHERE rn = 1
) S ON T.teamName = S.teamName
WHEN MATCHED THEN

UPDATE
SET
    teamScore = S.teamScore,
    teamTotalGoals = S.teamTotalGoals,
    teamSlogan = S.teamSlogan,
    topScorerStats = S.topScorerStats,
    bestPasserStats = S.bestPasserStats

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ROW;
```

With `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY teamName ORDER BY ingestionDate DESC) AS rn`, I take only the most recent row if I have duplicates on my unique key `teamName`.

I assume my destination table doesn't contains duplicates.
To work properly, `merge` query shouldn't have duplicates in the staging and final table.

I used my own query with these examples for simplicity but don't hesitate to adapt your query.

I also share with you an article on this topic, if you are interested [Remove BigQuery Duplicates](https://medium.com/google-cloud/remove-duplicates-in-bigquery-batch-pipeline-with-airflow-and-dataflow-2e7da5772c4d)